# "more fully" is like "fully"

Tags: meaning

I see in many places you use "more fully". I think "more" and "fully" have the same meaning and don't need we use the both, one of them is sufficient.
 Why do you use them together?

context is:
 The choice of article dependents upon the noun and the context this. This will be explained more fully below.
 Thanks.

Comment: What is the source? Looks like the source is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: http://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/articles/

Comment: In above like there is

Answer (score 2):

More fully can mean "more completely" or "in more detail," so it does make sense. Also, it is the only correct way to compare "fully," an adverb.

Adverbs ending in "-ly" are normally compared with "more" and "most," *there are some exceptions though*

Eg

> She finished more quickly than I did.
>
> Carol sings more beautifully than Mary.

Even though "fully" is the adverb form of the adjective "full," we cannot say "fullier." "More fully" is correct.

Comment: can't we ay only "fully"? if I can, what is differenced between "fully" and "more fully"?

Comment: "Fully" explained means explained in full, while "More fully" does not imply entirety.The 'more' here, refers to the little explanation already given.

Comment: I asked meaning of "more fully" not "more"?

Comment: When you say, "This will be explained more fully below" , it implies that there already is an explanation present, albeit not in a detailed manner.

Comment: You could consider it as a comparative form of "fully". i.e. the explanation below is **more** complete or detailed than the one already provided